# Filtrar com select em php

Tags: php, mysql

tenho este código com os 3 selects para filtrar uma consulta:

```
<form class="shadowbox6" action="" method="post">
    <strong><label for="Estado Encomenda">Estado Encomenda</label></strong>
        <select name="pesquisar"> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.EstadoEncomendas"; 
                $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){ 
                    echo '<option value="'.$ln['Estado'].'"> '.$ln['Estado'].'</option>'; 
                } 
            ?> 
        </select>
        <strong><label for="Valência">Valência</label></strong>
        <select name="pesquisar"> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.Destinos WHERE Id IN (1,2,3)"; 
                $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){ 
                    echo '<option value="'.$ln['Destino'].'"> '.$ln['Destino'].'</option>'; 
                } 
            ?> 
        </select>
        <strong><label for="Requerente">Requerente</label></strong>
        <select name="pesquisar"> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.Requerentes WHERE Id IN (1,2,4,5,8)"; 
                $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){ 
                    echo '<option value="'.$ln['Requerente'].'"> '.$ln['Requerente'].'</option>'; 
                } 
            ?> 
        </select>
        <button class="botao" type="submit">Consultar</button>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['pesquisar']))){
    $pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];

$result_cursos = "SELECT IdRequisicao, 
       CASE WHEN centrodb.EncomendasGerais.Estado IN (1,2,6) THEN DATE(DataEncomenda)
       WHEN centrodb.EncomendasGerais.Estado IN (3,4,5,7) THEN DataAprovacao END AS `Data`,
       IdTipoProduto,
       IdProduto,
       Quantidade,
       IdRequerente,
       IdDestino,
       Fornecedor,
       centrodb.EstadoEncomendas.Estado,
       Preco

FROM centrodb.EncomendasGerais LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.EstadoEncomendas

on centrodb.EstadoEncomendas.Id = centrodb.EncomendasGerais.Estado

WHERE centrodb.EstadoEncomendas.Estado LIKE '%$pesquisar%' AND IdDestino LIKE '%$pesquisar%' AND IdRequerente LIKE '%$pesquisar%'
...
}
```

Se utilizar só o primeiro select funciona bem o filtro, se adicionar as 3 possibilidades de filtro já não funciona.

Comment: Coloque os selects com names diferentes, e na hora de fazer a consulta, trate se recebeu algum post vindo de cada select antes de adicioná-lo na query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O name dos campos selects é o mesmo, então o ultimo exibido na tela e preenchido é o que fica guardado no $_POST["pesquisar"], por isso não esta dando certo. Se vc printar a sua query vai vai perceber que os três parâmetros ficaram com o mesmo valor.

Tente usar names diferentes nos selects e criar três variáveis de pesquisa, uma para cada select. Algo como :

```
<select name="pesquisar_estado"> 
<select name="pesquisar_destino"> 
<select name="pesquisar_requerente">
```

e no php vc recebe cada select em uma variavel

```
if(isset($_POST['pesquisar_estado']))){
   $pesquisar_requerente = $_POST['pesquisar_requerente'];
}
if(isset($_POST['pesquisar_destino']))){
   $pesquisar_destino = $_POST['pesquisar_destino'];
}
if(isset($_POST['pesquisar_requerente']))){
   $pesquisar_requerente = $_POST['pesquisar_requerente'];
}
```